# Create Helper to Concatenate Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, view-helpers

I may be looking at this all wrong but within my view (Using Active Admin) I would like to concatenate 3 attributes into one, so in my case, forename, middlename and surname into one string, with each part of the name separated by a space

So far i have come up with this

```
column "Name" do |member|
  member.forename +  member.middlename + member.surname
end
```

I also thought i could map the results

```
column "Name" do |member|
  member.map {|m| m.forename,  m.middlename, m.surname }
end
```

But that throws an error

So a helper would look something like this (as far as i can see it)

```
def fullname(member)
  member.forename +  member.middlename + member.surname
end
```

I think im confusing this somewhere along the line as i have 3 attributes I need to pass through the helper dont I?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. First, why don't you put this on the member model. Second, you should use interpolation over concatenation.

```
def fullname
  "#{self.forename} #{self.middlename} #{self.surname}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What three attributes? You have a single member, that *has* three attributes.

That said: [ActiveAdmin provides integration with Draper](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/11-decorators.html). Consider using a decorator instead, put `fullname` in the decorator, then just reference `fullname` as if it's a model property.

You could also put it in the model if it actually makes sense to do so.